# How to perform certain platform specific instructions in net standard?

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, .net-standard

I would like to write a logging library in net standard and use it in net framework and net 6.

Within this class library I want to perform an action if this library is used in net framework.

How could I achieve this ?

This is the code for net framework

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
        .WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate, outputTemplate: OutputTemplate)
        .WriteTo.GrafanaLoki("http://localhost:3100", outputTemplate: OutputTemplate, createLevelLabel: true)
        .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name)
        .Enrich.WithProcessId()
        .Enrich.WithThreadId()
        .Enrich.WithMachineName()
        .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
        .Enrich.WithEnvironmentName()
        .CreateLogger();
```

The same thing for NET 6 - the difference is when reading settings from the config file

```
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate, outputTemplate: OutputTemplate)
            .WriteTo.GrafanaLoki("http://localhost:3100", outputTemplate: OutputTemplate, createLevelLabel: true)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name)
            .Enrich.WithProcessId()
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
            .Enrich.WithEnvironmentName()
            .CreateLogger();
```

If it is running in net framework it should run `.ReadFrom.AppSettings()` else `.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)`

How is it done ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your library has no business poking around in the application configuration in the first place, regardless of where it's coming from. Invert the dependency and have the application inject the configuration into the library as part of startup. Arguably this whole method should be relegated to a convenience method that just sets the defaults, giving the application the option to override specifics, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: You want to _write_ or you want to _use_? If _write_: why tag serilog?

Comment: Notwithstanding the comments above, you can use [`Environment.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.version?view=net-6.0) to determine the CLR version for the current process.

Comment: Do both code paths compile on both versions of the framework? If yes, you can use a version check using `Environment.Version`, if not, you need to build your library in multi-TFM mode and use #if's.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me to `Environment.Version`.

As stated:

```
For.NET Core 3.x and.NET 5+, the Environment.Version property returns the .NET runtime version number.

For the .NET Framework Versions 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2, the Environment.Version property returns a Version object whose string representation has the form 4.0.30319.xxxxx.
        
For the .NET Framework 4.6 and later versions, and.NET Core versions before 3.0, it has the form 4.0.30319.42000.
```

This means difficulties in case of .NET Core 2 versions.
It's why I decided to check if there is an appsettings.json file.

I ended up with is:

```
public static class Configure
{
    private const string OutputTemplate =
        "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {ApplicationName} {Level} {ProcessId} {ThreadId} {MachineName} {EnvironmentName} {EnvironmentUserName} {SourceContext}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";

    public static void Logging<T>() where T : class
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AvailableSettings()
            .WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate, outputTemplate: OutputTemplate)
            .WriteTo.GrafanaLoki("http://localhost:3100", outputTemplate: OutputTemplate, createLevelLabel: true)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name)
            .Enrich.WithProcessId()
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
            .Enrich.WithEnvironmentName()
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    private static LoggerConfiguration AvailableSettings(this LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration)
    {
        if (!HasJsonConfigFile())
        {
            return settingConfiguration.AppSettings();
        }

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        return settingConfiguration.Configuration(configuration);
    }

    private static bool HasJsonConfigFile()
    {
        return File.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json"));
    }
}
```